# Multiple divs that wrap down, span 100% width across the page, are dynamic in width, and that equally wrap

Tags: css

Ok I thought this was going to be easy... but I cannot seem to wrap my head around it.

```
div.Navigation {
width:9.090909090909091%;
float: left;
border:1px solid #333;
text-align:center;
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle with further insight into what I am trying to do. Hope it makes sense.

http://jsfiddle.net/ufntosrn/1/

Hoping this does not get crazy... be kind to me lol

Comment: That large comment, in the CSS portion of your JS Fiddle, should be included - as the question - here, *in your question*.

Comment: So, if you have 1 div on line 2, you want it to be 100% width on its own?  And the divs in line 1 are all the same width (being the minimum width for a div)?

Comment: ok, bloody hell... i am just going to go with ten divs... that will at least get this at a point where I can beat on it from there... so if one div has to wrap due to screen size, five of them would wrap. and, lets say it has to go all the way down to only four divs being able to fit... that would make it so there would be 2 rows plus another row of 2 columns... and thus my problem comes into play yet again. oh the agony.

Answer (score 0):

CSS can't do this, by itself, as while it has a `calc()` function, it lacks any means by which the number of elements could be found, which is required for any dynamic solution. That said, if you can set the `width` of the elements using JavaScript then this becomes relatively easy:

```js
// gets all the <div> elements with the class of 'Navigation':
var navigationElems = document.querySelectorAll('div.Navigation'),
    // determines the percentage (of the appropriate parent element):
    width = 100/navigationElems.length;

// iterates over the array-like navigationElems NodeList, using
// Array.prototype.forEach():
Array.prototype.forEach.call(navigationElems, function (div) {
  // div is the current <div> element, here
  // setting its width to that of the width variable, in percent:
    div.style.width = width + '%';
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
div.Navigation {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-align: center;
  /* ensures that the sizing of the element includes
     the padding-, and border-, width: */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="Navigation">
    <a href="">Text</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Navigation">
    <a href="">Text</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Navigation">
    <a href="">Text</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Navigation">
    <a href="">Text Long</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Navigation">
    <a href="">Text Longer</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Navigation">
    <a href="">Text Really Long</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Navigation">
    <a href="">1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Navigation">
    <a href="">Text</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Navigation">
    <a href="">Text</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Navigation">
    <a href="">Text</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Navigation">
    <a href="">Text</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)<sup>[compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)</sup>.
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style).